# What is the purpose of empty constructor of DbContext Class in EF Code First Approach?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constructor, ef-code-first

I have the simple context class definition:

```
namespace PowerSupply.Persistance.Facade
{
    class PowerSupplyDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public PowerSupplyDBContext() : base("PowerSupplyDatabase")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

There is nothing inside the body of

```
public PowerSupplyDBContext() : base("PowerSupplyDatabase")
            {
```

what is the purpose of this empty constructor. How does this empty constructor works?

Comment: Well, it may appear empty, but note that it still calls the constructor of the parent class with the argument `"PowerSupplyDatabase"`

Comment: Got it. But I have question: why such pretension or style in this method? I am confused with my own code. It seems to me that this method do nothing as method body is empty. Is any code will go inside the body?

Comment: [See Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings)

Comment: It passes "PowerSupplyDatabase" as an argument to the base class constructor so it does not do nothing.

Comment: Maybe also [read up on constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors), this convention is not specific to EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best practice to include an empty constructor in any class that might be used by a third party / other project / anywhere that the compiler can't catch a change in the class.

If you omit the empty constructor, and that class is used by a third party or in another one of your projects/applications, then you can't later change that class to include a constructor with arguments. Otherwise, all the uses of this class that previously did not rely on passing constructor arguments will break, because they will have no empty-constructor to reference.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic... If you add a constructor with parameters at a later date surely you could add the parameterless constructor then too, assuming you want a parameterless constructor... The reason you need a constructor call here even with an empty body is because there is no other way to call the base constructor.

Comment: Pretty much what @Chris said.

Answer (score 5):

It calls the constructor of the base class. So it is not empty. It just doesnt add something new.

There are many reasons you could use that "empty" constructor.

You may not have any new  properties, or you instantiate those properties somewhere else (i dont recommend)

You may just want to add functionality (new methods) so you extend the class, and implement new methods using the properties and methods of base class. So you dont need the constructor to do something new, opposed to the base class.

Or it has many constructors, and you use the empty constructor in circumstances you need to use limited functionality of the class, or default values.